# Memory size error

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In my Magento store, I got the below error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2122317824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 546563077 bytes) in
>   /home/wanstallscustom/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple.php
>   on line 103

Our server admin says that 2GB(memory Limit) is the limit right now and he said it should be more than enough.

Please suggest me any solution to handle such type situation.

Answer (score -1):

You have few variants:

**1.** you can check your **memory_limit** in your **public_html/.htacess** file, default value there is 256M you can try to change that value with 2048M

> php_value memory_limit 2048M

**2.** In your **public_html** folder you have a **php.ini.sample** file, just rename that file with **php.ini** and change the value 64M with 2048M:

> memory_limit = 2048M

Comment: there is already 2gb memory limit

Comment: she need to try can be just a server issue

Comment: Our server admin says that 2GB is the limit right now and he said it should be more than enough.

Comment: but what you in this file? home/wanstallscustom/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple.php  can you put the code here?

Comment: No. I didn't add anything in this file